# In Angular Material, how to dynamically pass the columns that are to be conidered for filtering to the custom filterPredicate function

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-table

I have the following form, representing a dropdown for the corresponding columns. I am trying to apply filter on the columns only on which user has made selection in dropdown.

- If user selected say  `age:30` from `age` dropdown my filter has to consider only `age` column in its filter,
- If user selected say  `city:Washington` from `city` dropdown my filter has to consider only `city` column in its filter.
- If user selected say  `city:Washington` from `city` dropdown and `name:Jhon` from `name` dropdown my filter has to consider only `name` ,`city` columns in its filter.

i.e the columns to be considered for filter is dynamic based on which dropdowns user is making selection.

The issue I am seeing is `filter` of `MatDataSource` is a `string`, I can pass a filter value but cannot mention which column the filter value has to be checked.

My code looks like below with custom `filterPredicate` function. It works fine except for the cell values `""` (empty string). Is there a better and correct way to achieve this

-- * html *--

```
<form #filterForm="ngForm" [formGroup]="filterGroup" >
  <div class="filter-fields-container">

      <mat-select formControlName="name">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let name of names" [value]="name">
          {{name}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>

  

      <mat-select formControlName="age">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let age of ages" [value]="age">
          {{age}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>

  

      <mat-select formControlName="city">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let city of cities" [value]="city">
          {{city}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>

  </div>
  <div class="filter-buttons">
    <button type="button" (click)="applyFilter()"> Apply Filter</button>
    <button type="button" (click)="clearFilter()"> Clear Filter</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

--* model *--

```
applyFilter(){
    if(this.filterGroup){

        const nameFilterValue = this.filterGroup.get('name')!.value.trim().toLowerCase();
        const ageFilterValue = this.filterGroup.get('age')!.value.trim().toLowerCase();
        const cityFilterValue = this.filterGroup.get('city')!.value.trim().toLowerCase();

        this.sampleDataSource.filterPredicate = (data: SampleDataItem, filter:string)=>{
          let resultMatch : boolean =  true;
          const nameMatches = filter.includes(data.name.trim().toLowerCase());
          const cityMatches = filter.includes(data.city.trim().toLowerCase());
          const ageMatches = filter.includes(data.age.trim().toLowerCase());


          if(nameFilterValue && nameFilterValue!==""){
            resultMatch = resultMatch && nameMatches
          }
          if(cityFilterValue && cityFilterValue!==""){
            resultMatch = resultMatch && cityMatches
          }
          if(ageFilterValue && ageFilterValue!==""){
            resultMatch = resultMatch && ageMatches
          }
            return resultMatch
        }
        this.sampleDataSource.filter = [nameFilterValue , ageFilterValue, cityFilterValue].filter(Boolean).join('');
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please put up the code on stackblitz and share for understanding better?